# Using compiler directives for conditional attributes

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-directives

I wish to make an attribute conditional based on compilation mode.

For example this is `MyFunction()` which is decorated with the attribute `MyAttribute()`:

```
<MyAttribute()>  
Private Function MyFunction() As Boolean
....
End Function
```

However I *only* want the attribute to be applied when DEBUG is true, which sounds like a great place to use [compiler directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx):

```
#If Debug Then
<MyAttribute()>
#End If
Private Function MyFunction() As Boolean
....
End Function
```

However this seems to require a continuation character ( _) which in turn affects the `#End If` (unexpected token).

How would I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worst case, you'd could do:

```
#If Debug Then
<MyAttribute()>
Private Function MyFunction() As Boolean
#Else
Private Function MyFunction() As Boolean
#End If
```

This is probably due to the line continuation processing occurring before the pre-processing. For example, this is valid:

```
#If 1 = _
  1 Then

#End If
```

In your case, you are expecting the line continuation to occur after pre-processing.

Comment: Is this a bug with the compiler then?

Comment: @m.edmondson - Updated my answer with my answer to your comment ;-)